# What would make grammatic sense: DC current or just DC, when describing type of current?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am writing about currents like AC and DC types. AC stands for Alternating Current and DC stands for Direct Current. Would it make sense when writing if i wrote like this: "I am going to use DC current" or "I am going to use DC"? It sounds grammatically wrong when saying "DC current", because i am repeating current twice in an expanded form of DC. But when saying just "DC", it also sounds wrong, because I'm not describing what DC is.

Can you please tell me which is the correct form?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you will use DC or AC repeatedly, you could spell it out the first time so less awkward in abbreviated form later as a noun instead of adjective. E.g., "I will be using direct current (DC)." (although a sentence more specific to your topic might suit, e.g. "DC sources" or "direct-current batteries"). "AC current" is redundant (in a syntactically incorrect way) as is "ATM machine" and "PIN number".

Comment: Yes, good point.

Comment: Correct usage and satisfaction of one's logical arguments for a usage are not always the same thing. Definitions usually broaden, and sometimes even switch, over time.

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions about phrases such as PIN number, e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/pin-number-why-do-we-say-it

Comment: When a techie uses the term "DC" he/she hardly recalls that the "C" stands for "current".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on a science/tech web site.

Comment: Many questions on ELU are tied to specific fields, like ["What countries use "bond" to refer to a security deposit?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105261/what-countries-use-bond-to-refer-to-a-security-deposit) and  ["Definite article in Maths: "(the) function f"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244182/definite-article-in-maths-the-function-f) where the question often centers on an issue about English. *DC* is in common use.

Comment: @HotLicks Wouldn't a techie be more likely to know that DC means "direct current"? // Ywa, DC stands for "direct current", but not only that, DC means "direct current", too. So say DC, not DC current.  An initialism may be used as the noun phrase it stands for --- it's not restricted to being a modifier of another noun.

Comment: @RosieF Speaking as someone with a Master of Engineering degree in Electrical Engineering, I'm likely to use the term "DC" without bothering to think about what it means.

Comment: You could always say "DC power", "DC electricity" or "a DC power supply". There would be no tautology in those cases but it would be absolutely clear that you are not referring to the District of Columbia or a Debit Card.

Answer (score 1):

As you have pointed out already, saying "DC/AC current" would mean you're repeating current twice. One wouldn't say "DC current is the one-directional flow" but rather, "DC is the one-directional flow".

A (probable) reason why the second sentence sounds weird is because is because, technically, you wouldn't say **you're using DC** but instead **you're using a DC source**.

> "I am going to use a *direct current (DC) source.*"

---

### Update

Did some extra research, because Physics isn't really my area of expertise. According to Wikipedia:

> The abbreviations AC and DC are often used to mean simply alternating and direct, as when they modify current or voltage.

This means that it is, in fact, **socially acceptable** to say "DC current" & "AC current" despite its redundancy.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my first doubt :) .But what if the context was: "In the wire, there is DC source". 'source', doesn't make sense here, so would 'current' here be an exemption?

Comment: For those instances, you could always expand DC: "direct current flows through wire A". (PS: I've updated my answer a bit)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: I'm surprised that justification for 'DC current' is out there. Good trawling! But please add a link to the Wikipedia reference. // 'PIN Number' is another common redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

*DC current* is in common use:

> The abbreviation "dc" is so much used that it is common language to
> say **dc current (tautology)** and dc voltage (contradictory)... The
> **dc current** may be pulsed, but...
> A *galvanic* current is the same as a **dc current**, and the term is used... [S. Grimnes and Ø. G. Martinsen; *Bioimpedance and Bioelectrical Basics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bioimpedance_and_Bioelectricity_Basics/vttnCrG2GawC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22DC%20current%22&pg=PA159&printsec=frontcover)

> What is **DC Current**?
> DC stands for Direct Current, although it is often referred to as **“DC
> Current”**.  [electrical4U.com](https://www.electrical4u.com/dc-current/)

> To test the setting of the pulse time, two samples are measured in liquid nitrogen with pulse and **DC current**, and the result ...
>
> Fig. 6.6: Comparison of critical current in liquid nitrogen with **DC
> current supply** and pulse current supply. [Liu and Yingzhen; *Design
> of a Superconducting DC Wind Generator*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Design_of_a_superconducting_DC_wind_gene/nC0PEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22DC%20current%22&pg=PA116&printsec=frontcover)

> The peak current rating of the switches is equal to the **DC current
> source** and is lower compared to the VSI case. [J. C. Whitaker; *The
> Electronics Handbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Electronics_Handbook/9VHMBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22DC%20current%20source%22&pg=PA1074&printsec=frontcover)

Google Scholar turns up about 3,900 papers with "DC current", for example:

[M. Dyakonov and M. Shur; "Shallow water analogy for a ballistic field effect transistor: New mechanism of plasma wave generation by **dc current**"](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.71.2465)

[N. Deng et al.; "A **DC current flow controller** for meshed modular multilevel converter multiterminal HVDC grids"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7086155)

Comment: @BublooMohanrajh *DC current source/supply* is fine; see examples.